# FQL: Order photos by likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Is there anyway to retrieve photos ordered by the number of likes in FQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PLEASE NOTE: I have never played with FQL before, but I need this exact solution *yesterday*, so I gave it a go!

Try adding references to "like_info" in the first line in the previous answer (maybe like_info is new since you asked this?):

```
$fql = "SELECT like_info, object_id,src_small,link FROM photo WHERE aid = '2389563453799923709' ORDER BY like_info created DESC";
        $param  =   array(
            'method'    => 'fql.query',
            'query'     => $fql,
            'callback'  => ''
        );

        $photos = $facebook->api($param);
```

This may well give you answers returned in order from most to least liked. At least, it worked for me! :)

Comment: Awesome! Looks like it's new: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/02/29/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/. Also, it looks like you should be ordering by `like_info.like_count`, just to be more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

**Please note:** This solution is no longer require as `like_info` has been added to photo

---

So, I'm guessing this is impossible to do nicely? Here's the ugly solution:

```
$fql = "SELECT object_id,src_small,link FROM photo WHERE aid = '2389563453799923709' ORDER BY created DESC";
        $param  =   array(
            'method'    => 'fql.query',
            'query'     => $fql,
            'callback'  => ''
        );

        $photos = $facebook->api($param);

        if (count($photos) > 0) { 
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($photos); $i++) {
                $objectId = $photos[$i]['object_id'];
                $like_count = $facebook->api('/'.$objectId.'/likes');
                $photos[$i]['likes'] = count($like_count['data']);
            }
        }

        function cmp($a, $b) {
            if ($a['likes'] == $b['likes'])
                return 0;
            return $a['likes'] > $b['likes'] ? -1 : 1;
        }

        usort($photos, 'cmp');
```